# Can I use a DC 60W 18v 3A solar pannel to power my macbook pro 15" retina mid-2012?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, power, magsafe

I have found this solar pannel ( https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Suaoki-60-w-Panneau-Solaire-5-v-USB-et-18-v-DC-Sortie-Portable-Pliable-Puissance/32935273533.html?spm=a2g0w.search0104.8.83.3f714267rqy4Q1&priceBeautifyAB=0 ).

I am already using another one, smaller, for charging usb powerbanks while traveling and it does the job well.

I have now found a DC to magsafe 2 adapter that suits the 60W solar pannel.

The Apple DC power magsafe 2 for the Macbook has the follwing written on it : "Output - 20v / 4.25A max."

Is this solar pannel suitable ?

What should I be looking for when looking for power appliances to charge this Macbook ( W, v, A )?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ,the math goes like this

Volt x Amps = Watts

First important factor is the Voltage. It has to be the right one for the circuits otherwise they burn up. You would not connect 120 Volt to magsafe.

Next is the Current (Amps) it is the consumption. Usually they are controlled by the consumer (Battery in this case). You can not have to much of it since Battery only takes what it needs. The specification for Maximum Amps is for protection of the connector (plug), otherwise to much of it can burn the wires/connectors.

The 85 W charger (20x4.25) are used with 15" and 17" MacBook Pro, so you might be bit on low end with your 60w. It will charge but slower.

If you are in the wilderness with no plugs and on you Solar, keep an eye from time to time on the Charging.

About this mac > System report > Power.

There you will see if the battery is charging or been depleted.

Look at he Amperage (mA) number, if it is negative (-) then your battery is been depleted.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The voltage of the solar pannel is 18v. The Macbook is 20v. I won't overburn the circuits but would 18v be sufficient to charge the battery while the original power outlet of the Macbook is indicated as being 20v ?

Comment: The 20v is the maximum spec, the actual Voltage coming out is from 14 to 18 Volt, so you are fine.

Comment: While it might not actually charge the battery while the macbook is turned on because of the lower wattage, it should at least slow down the battery's depletion and while the macbook is turned off, the battery should charge but slower than with the original DC power, am I correct ?

Comment: @Sam yes you are correct.

Comment: @Sam just keep an eye on the Amperage from time to time.