# Is it safe to charge my MacBook Pro with a 24W solar panel with USB-C?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, charging

I charged my 2016 13" [MacBook Pro i7 with Touch Bar](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/G0SF2LL/A/Refurbished-133-inch-Macbook-Pro-33GHz-Dual-core-Intel-Core-i7-with-Retina-Display-Space-Gray) 
this morning with a 24W solar panel.

I am not sure if this is safe to do longterm for the the laptop. Am I damaging the MacBook if I do this? What would happen if I used a 60W solar panel?

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290636/can-a-low-wattage-adapter-fully-recharge-the-battery-of-a-turned-off-macbook and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338872/can-i-use-a-dc-60w-18v-3a-solar-pannel-to-power-my-macbook-pro-15-retina-mid-20